# What is the corresponding infinite series for this infinite infinite product?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, power-series, infinite-product

What is the infinite series corresponding to the infinite product below?
$$f(\alpha,x)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1+\frac{x}{\alpha^n}\right)$$

Edit:
Martin R told me to speak about what I have gotten up to now about how to expand this, so: up to now I only got really complicated expressions with double sums for example. I think this is related to partitions but I don't know exactly how. The reason for thinking this function is related to partitions is because at $x=1$ it is the generating function at $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ for the partition function, and at $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ it actually converges, as long as $\alpha>1$ (for $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$

Edit 2:
I am looking for a clean expression like a power series with some coefficients I don't yet know. I wanted to know this because I was trying to evaluate something else that is related to partitions looking at it now.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @MartinR Oh, sorry, I didn't know. Up to now I only got really complicated expressions with double sums for example. I think this is related to partitions but I don't know exactly how. The reason for thinking this function is related to partitions is because at $x=1$ it is the generating function at $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ for the partition function, and at $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ it actually converges, as long as $|\alpha|>1$ (for $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer obviously is:

$$1+{x\over\alpha-1}+{x^2\over(\alpha-1)\cdot(\alpha^2-1)}+\dots+{x^n\over(\alpha-1)\cdot...\cdot(\alpha^n-1)}+\dots$$

How so?

Well, what is the coefficient at $x^n$? That's an infinite sum of various inverse powers of $\alpha$, some of them identical. How many terms $\frac1{\alpha^m}$ are there? As many as there are sets of $n$ different integers that sum to $m$. Is there any shorter way to express this? Why, sure; it is the same as in the problem *"in how many ways can you give such-and-such sum in change, if you have such-and-such coins"*.

Taking the term at $x^2$ as an example:

$${1\over(\alpha-1)(\alpha^2-1)} = {1\over\alpha^3}\cdot\frac1{\left(1-{1\over\alpha}\right)\left(1-{1\over\alpha^2}\right)} = \\= \left({1\over\alpha}+{1\over\alpha^2}+{1\over\alpha^3}+\dots\right)\left({1\over\alpha^2}+{1\over\alpha^4}+{1\over\alpha^6}+\dots\right)= \\ =
{1\over\alpha^3}+{1\over\alpha^4}+{2\over\alpha^5}+{2\over\alpha^6}+{3\over\alpha^7}+{3\over\alpha^8}+\dots$$
which is the same as I said earlier: the sum of inverse powers of $\alpha$ with certain combinatorial expression in the numerator.

So it goes.

Comment: How do you know it is those coefficients exactly? Can you explain in more detail how you got to that shorter way? I really want to understand this.

Comment: Can you find the coefficient at $x^1$ yourself, so that I knew where to start?

Comment: Actually, yes, I get why the first coefficient would be $\frac{x}{\alpha-1}$; namely because of the sum of all the $\frac{x}{\alpha^n}$. @IvanNeretin

Comment: Thanks that is really helpful.